# PHP: Перебор массива с отрицательным условием else

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть переменная и массив:

```
  $test =  '10';
  $arr = array('один' =>'1','два' =>'2', 'три' =>'3','четыре' =>'4','пять' =>'5');
```

Мне нужно перебрать его таким образом, чтобы если НЕ оказалось ни одного совпадения переменной `$test` и значения массива, то вывести ОДНУ итерацию из всего перебора с сообщением "Ничего не нашлось". А если нашлось, то вернуть ключ массива.

Например:

```
  foreach($arr as $key => $val){
      if($val == $test){
          echo key= ' . $key;
      }else{
          echo 'Ничего не нашлось';   //Нужно вывести ОДИН раз.
      }
  }
```

Функция in_array() в моем случае не подойдет.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: почему `in_array()` не подойдет?

Comment: @ArtOsi потому что у меня большой массив с множеством значений, если они пересекутся, то вернётся не правильный ключ.

Comment: @Pavel где в вашем вопросе вообще что-либо про вывод ключа?

Comment: @teran Я привел простейший пример и указал, что 'in_array()' не подойдет. Спасибо за ответ. Ваш лучший.

Comment: @Pavel если надо вернуть ключ первого совпавшего элемента, то ответ Эдуарда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768478/223826 будет оптимальным, т.к. array_search как раз и возвращает ключ первого совпавшего элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не мешайте мух со котлетами. Определите в цикле что ничего не нашлось, и уже после цикла выведите нужное сообщение.

```
$found = false;
foreach($arr as $value){
    if($value == $test){
        echo "test = $value";
        $found = true;
    }
}

if(!$found) echo "ничего не нашлось";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array($test, $arr)) {
   echo 'test = ' . $test;
} 
else {
   echo 'Ничего не нашлось';   //Нужно вывести ОДИН раз.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему это она не подойдёт?

```
if (! in_array( $test, array_values( $arr) ) ) {
    // нет в массиве
}
```

Comment: Например массив $arr = array('id' = '1', last_id = '1'); Мне нужно вернуть ключ 'id', а 'last' не надо.

Comment: Ну так это совсем не то, что в вопросе и вашем коде. Внесите ваш комментарий в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать поиск значения и возврат ключа:

```
if (($k = array_search($test, $arr)) !== false) {
    echo $arr[$k];
} else {
    echo 'Ничего не нашлось';  
}
```